# Computational complexity of for loops-Contradicting with myself

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I have a contradiction by analyzing the running time of a program. For example, consider the following piece of code:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
         .....
    }
}
```

Here, the computational complexity of 1st for loop is O(n<sup>2</sup>), and for the second loop it is O(n). However, the second loop is executed n<sup>2</sup> times whereas first loop is executed n times. For example, if we put a cout statement inside the inner loop, it outputs n<sup>2</sup> times, but if we put a cout somewhere inside the 1st loop but outside the inner loop, it outputs n times. So why do we say the complexity of inner loop is O(n), but for outer loop it is O(n<sup>2</sup>). **We say the complexity of outer loop is O(n<sup>2</sup>) but it executes n times, why is this the case?** Am i doing something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: How come first loop will run for n^2 times.?

Comment: @Vallabh Patade that is where i am contradicting. We say the complexity of outer loop is O(n^2) but it executes n times

Comment: We say complexity of code snippet is n^2.

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop executes n times, which takes O(n). The outer loop executes the inner loop n times, but you have to account for the cost of the inner loop for each of those n outer loop executions. This makes it O(n * O(n)) = O(n^2).

Comment: I know, but for example, if we put a cout statement inside the inner loop, it outputs n^2 times, but if we put a cout somewhere inside the 1st loop but outside the inner loop, it outputs n times. So why do we say the complexity of inner loop is O(n), but for outer loop it is O(n^2)

Comment: @YasinRazlık: Because the computation complexity is not "how many times does a loop run", but rather "how many times are statements inside your routine executed" (roughly). In your case, while executing the outer loop, the statements in the inner loop (eg. `j++`) run O(n^2) times, hence the complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Outer loop will run for n times and inner loop will run for n times for every iteranion of outer loop making inner loop to run for n^2 times. Thus statements in inner loop will get executed for n^2 times.

Comment: yup, its the inner loop which runs n^2 times and has time complexity O(n^2). Not the outer one

Answer (score 0):

Let say, n = 7 ; then

```
for(int i=0 ; i< 7 ; i++) //time complexity is : (1) + (7+1) + (7)
{
    for(int j=0;j<7;j++) //  time complexity is: (1) + [(7+1)+(7+1)+(7+1)+(7+1)+(7+1)+(7+1)+(7+1)] + (7)
    {
         .....
    }
}
```

**Total time complexity** = [2+2(7)] + [1 + (7+1)^2 + 7]

Now replace 7 = n ; We will get

**Total time complexity** = [2+2n] + [1 + (n+1)^2 + n] = 2 + 2n + 1 + (n^2 + 2n + 1) + n = n^2 + 5n + 4

Here the dominant term is n^2. So the worst case will be **O(n^2)**